# Signal power and signal-to-noise ratio with repeaters

Tags: snr, bandwidth

[image]

I am trying to solve this question but I am confused on some aspects

1. When solving part B what power signal will we use. Will we use power signal before repeater 2 or after repeater 2 (x5)
2. When finding maximum bit rate what should the SNR value? should it be average of all the SNR or what?

Comment: Can you please clarify if this question is homework?

Comment: This is not a homework this is a practice question which might come with changed values in our exam.

Comment: I know this isn't mentioned above, but you need to make sure that you know whether these are *amplify and forward* or *decode and forward* repeaters; that makes a lot of difference for the calculation!